# Play Framework 2.5 Test ApplicationLifecycle Guice Specs2 setup

Tags: scala, guice, playframework-2.5

I am trying to run some functional tests with `play2-reactivemongo`. I will try to be as concrete as possible, but if something is missing please let me know.

My dependencies are here

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" %  "0.12.0",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "4.0.0",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % "4.0.0" % "test",
  specs2 % Test
)
```

In `MongoUserDao.scala`

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection

class MongoUserDao @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends UserDao {
  val usersFuture = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("users"))
...
}
```

In `DaoSpecResources.scala`

```
trait DaoSpecResources {

  val timeout = DurationInt(10).seconds

  val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .configure(
      "play.modules.enabled" -> List("play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"),
      "mongodb.uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
    )
    .build

  val reactiveMongoApi = fakeApp.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]
  ...
}
```

When I try to run the test I get this error

```
[error] cannot create an instance for class daos.UserDaoSpec
[error]   caused by com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
[error]
[error] 1) No implementation for play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle was bound.
[error]   while locating play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
[error]     for parameter 1 at services.ApplicationTimer.<init>(ApplicationTimer.scala:24)
[error]   at Module.configure(Module.scala:23) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)
[error]
[error] 1 error
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by `app/services/ApplicationTimer.scala`, which depends on `ApplicationLifecycle`, but you haven't bound any implementation to `ApplicationLifecycle`. `ApplicationTimer` is a demo included in every new Play project. You should probably remove it completely if you don't need it, otherwise at least disable it if running in test mode. See [disabling modules](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTestingWithGuice#disable-modules) and [overriding modules](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTestingWithGuice#loaded-modules).

## Solution

However, since `DefaultReactiveMongoApi` also depends on `ApplicationLifecycle`, you'll need to provide a binding to an implementation of `ApplicationLifecycle`. The easiest way:

```scala
import play.api.inject.{ ApplicationLifecycle, DefaultApplicationLifecycle }
import play.api.inject.bind

trait DaoSpecResources {

  val timeout = DurationInt(10).seconds

  val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .configure(
      "play.modules.enabled" -> List("play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"),
      "mongodb.uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
    )
    .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
    .build

  val reactiveMongoApi = fakeApp.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]

  val lifecycle = fakeApp.injector.instanceOf[DefaultApplicationLifecycle]
  def stopApp = lifecycle.stop()

}
```

(added 5 lines: imports, `bindings`, `lifecycle` and `stopApp`)

Then, in your test spec, add `step(stopApp)` at the end, like so:

```scala
class FooSpec extends PlaySpecification with DaoSpecResources {

    // Your examples...

    step(stopApp)

}
```

## Alternative solution

Personally, I'd create a specialized trait extending `Specification` or `PlaySpecification` which would set up and tear down everything automatically, like [in this example from specs2 documentation](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Global+setup%2Fteardown).

```scala
trait PlayWithMongoSpecification extends PlaySpecification {

  val timeout = DurationInt(10).seconds

  val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .configure(
      "play.modules.enabled" -> List("play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"),
      "mongodb.uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
    )
    .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
    .build

  val reactiveMongoApi = fakeApp.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]

  val lifecycle = fakeApp.injector.instanceOf[DefaultApplicationLifecycle]
  def stopApp = lifecycle.stop()

  override def map(fs: =>Fragments) = fs ^ step(stopApp)

}

class FooSpec extends PlayWithMongoSpecification {

    // Your examples...

}
```

You may consider making `reactiveMongoApi` a `lazy val`.

Comment: @Pawel_Bartkiewicz thank you for your answer. I did not solve it yet. I need the ApplicationLifeCycle since it is a dependency of ReactiveMongoModule. I will keep trying.

Comment: @agusgambina The second part of my answer considered this. I've added detailed explanation with examples showing how to provide `ApplicationLifecycle`. Tested this in my project and it worked.

Comment: @Pawel_Bartkiewicz thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay. I really liked your alternative solution. I tried really to make it work but I could not. It seems that I am not giving some configuration to the default constructor of the play.modules.reactivemongo.DefaultReactiveMongoApi I am right?